# Tumblr Photoset's Lightbox showing images of different sizes

Tags: jquery, html, css, tumblr

Basically, I've recently started to mess around with Tumblr's coding and I've encountered a problem. I'm using the pixel union photoset script on my theme but for some reason, when I click to open the photoset's lightbox, the images displayed are of different sizes. The active image would be bigger than the rest. Any ideas why?

picture of the issue :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This has occurred to me when I have `width: 100%` or `height: auto` or something of the likes applied to all `img`'s. Try instead applying it to `img:not(.lightbox-image)`, it should fix the problem.